# Refactoring assemblies when implementing a Facade

Tags: c#, namespaces, assemblies, facade

I have two assemblies, `API` and a `FacadeAPI`. FacadeAPI makes using `API` simpler to use. Then I have a `Main` program that uses `FacadeAPI` assembly. So `Main` depends on `FacadeAPI` which depends on `API`.

There is are a few relatively small classes (really structs) inside `API` that are at the used everywhere including the `Main` program. I don't wan to include the entire `API` into both `FacadeAPI` and `Main` just to use these classes.

What is the standard thing to do here? Break out these classes into their own assembly so they can be easily referenced from all the dependent assemblies? This would work when you have source to `API`. Adding the whole `API` to `Main` seems prone to error let alone exposing the `API` to the `Main` program when all you want to do is expose the `FacadeAPI`, and in the case where you don't have the source to `API`, impossible to break out the small classes.

I could wrap the small classes in `FacadeAPI`but that just seems wasteful and needs unnecessary copying.

Comment: Seems like the best will be "Break out these classes into their own assembly so they can be easily referenced from all the dependent assemblies". For a good decision, too few details provided.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a separate assembly to hold your data models.  This way, all other assemblies can reference them without any circular reference issues.

Comment: What do you do when you don't have the source to API?